# Use WAMP as webserver on my local network for Drupal dev site

Tags: mysql, apache, drupal, drupal-6, wamp

I'm trying to set up my PC as a webserver so that users on the same network can access the Drupal 6 dev site I have installed locally. I've set a static IP for them to access, and set up the vhost to send the host they use to the site's subfolder in my www folder, but they get the Drupal error page with the message:

"The mysql error was: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known."

Can anyone help?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about invalid password settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: it was being caused by incorrect mysql user/pass in Drupal's settings.php